# How do I do math with javascript using an HTML drop down?

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to make this simple calculator calculate tax rates, but I'm obviously missing something, because I can't get it to work.

```js
function millrate() {
  var assessment = document.getElementById("assessment");
  var millrate = document.getElementById("millrate");
  var taxes = assessment * millrate / 1000;
  document.getElementById("taxes").innerHTML = 'Tax Amount = $' + taxes;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form>
      Combined Assessment Amount:<br>
      <input id="assessment" type="text" name="Assessment">
      <br> Tax Year:<br>
      <select id="millrate" name="TaxYear">
        <option value="10.0636">2017</option>
        <option value="9.9809">2016</option>
        <option value="9.9296">2015</option>
        <option value="10.1267">2014</option>
        <option value="10.4282">2013</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>
      <button type="button" onclick="millrate()">
          Click to Calculate Tax Amount
      </button>
    </form>

    <p id="taxes"></p>

  </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things - the button was inside the form, and you need to get the values from the inputs and parse them into numbers. Then you can do the calculations and return the result.

```js
function millrate() {
  var assessment = parseFloat(document.getElementById("assessment").value);
  var millrate = parseFloat(document.getElementById("millrate").value)/ 1000;
  var taxes = assessment * millrate ;
  document.getElementById("taxes").innerHTML = 'Tax Amount = $' + taxes;
}
```

```html
<form>
      Combined Assessment Amount:<br>
      <input id="assessment" type="text" name="Assessment">
      <br> Tax Year:<br>
      <select id="millrate" name="TaxYear">
        <option value="10.0636">2017</option>
        <option value="9.9809">2016</option>
        <option value="9.9296">2015</option>
        <option value="10.1267">2014</option>
        <option value="10.4282">2013</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>
    </form>
   <button type="button" onclick="millrate()">Click to Calculate Tax Amount</button>
   <p id = "taxes"></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `millrate()` function: be descriptive in naming your variables - you can always minimize later. So, in your case `var assessment` should actually be named `assessmentElement`.

Then your `input` elements, speficy the type `text`, `number`, `password`, etc. Set them to the right type (for UI), Then you can sanitize/validate in your logic (JS) in a number of ways, maybe using `typeOf`, for example.

Lastly, you really don't need a submit button. Simply attach a `change` listener to the select/dropdown to spit out the result on option selection.

Lastly, get rid of the `form` element wrapper. Use a `fieldset` instead. `form` has alot of hidden baked in functionality that I find is easier avoided.

Hope that helps.